# Where am I going wrong while trying to install sample database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I wanted to load the Sample Database Menagerie into MySQL. So, it's showing 'FAILED TO OPEN' in MySQL.
My text.file for the same is

```
Drop database if exists menagerie ;
CREATE DATABASE menagerie ;
USE menagerie ;
SOURCE C:/SampleDB/cr_pet_tbl.sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/SampleDB/pet.txt' INTO TABLE pet ;
SOURCE C:/SampleDB/ins_puff_rec.sql
SOURCE C:/SampleDB/cr_event_tbl.sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/SampleDB/event.txt' INTO TABLE event ;
```

[image]

And these are the details of Menagerie DB
[image]

I have also Uncompressed the file.
[image]

But still there's an error!

[image]

**Where am I going wrong please can anyone tell? Don't ignore please, it takes a lot of efforts to type so much here.**
I have downloaded Menagerie from MySQL site into a folder SampleDB on drive C.

Comment: This question was resolved in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115711/discussion-between-faaria-shaikh-and-nbk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was, the file was not in the Folder `C:/SampleDB`

the screenshot is from the temporary unzipped file.

After creating the foldeer and copying  the files, all was in order.

Comment: That BTW teaches you to not cut out (location url) the most important info in screenshots ,) people do that all the time.